# .bash_profile is empty after accidentally deleting everything, now sudo returns -bash: sudo: command not found

Tags: terminal

I was trying to set the directory for flutter, but when I did I accidentally deleted everything inside my bash_profile. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Recover the file from backup :-)

Comment: Where do you get the error? In a terminal tab/window which was already open when you deleted the file content, or in a new one created afterwards? What is the result of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: You probably deleted your PATH.  Type `echo $PATH` and post the result.  Also, try running `/usr/bin/sudo` Let me know if that still works.  But as @nohillside already alluded to - please say that you have a backup!

Comment: echo $PATH returns /Users/andyyeung/Developer/flutter/bin, while /usr/bin/sudo returns usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]
            [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-T timeout]
            [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-T timeout]
            [-u user] file ...

Comment: I get the error in a new terminal created after